# Admin panel for postgresql on Node.js server

Tags: linux, windows, node.js, postgresql

I want to host a Node project running with a postgreSQL db. However, when it is on the server I won't have a UI tool to easily view database entries. Does anyone know how I would go about creating a /admin domain to view / edit my postgreSQL db through an admin panel?

I'm using https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres as the client.

Comment: Writing a database admin UI isn't a trivial task. Consider using an existing one, and limiting your application to just the database support it needs to do its job and using existing admin tools for everything else.

Comment: @CraigRinger Oh god, no no I was never going create my own haha (Create was a terrible word). I just have no idea how I can set up an admin panel for postgreSQL on the server. Are there UI Tools I have to download and set up? Do some hosts provide you with a database UI at like /admin? If both what is the best for a small project? Sorry for the questions, I truly did research this, but I've only found information on setting up a PostgreSQL db etc.. I know how to do that. I don't know how to get it on my server domain eg.) www.domain.com/admin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use DB admin tools on a remote server you have a few options:

- `ssh` in and use `psql`. Easiest once you learn your way around `psql`.
- Use PgAdmin-III via an SSL connection to the sever, or using its ssh tunnel features
- Set up a web-based tool like phpPgAdmin on your web server, properly locked down, and access it over the browser.

Personally I'd stick with the basics.

Comment: uhhh I've looked into this a bit more, and it seems some hosts offer hosted databases, such as Heroku. This seems much easier to set up then having to obtain an SSH / SSL connection everytime to edit the DB for a small project. I think I'm going to just go with that option, thanks for the help though, I really appreciate it!

Comment: @BenCheng You'll still be using `psql`, PgAdmin-III, etc with them too, you know. Heroku for example exposes an SSL connection to PostgreSQL; exactly like you get when you fire up your own PostgreSQL instance and enable SSL. They don't come with web-based GUI database editors or anything.

Comment: Ah I see, thanks for schooling me Craig, I understand database connections better now!